# Is it possible to reuse a site with a different domain name, even if the domain that was attached to this site before is now on another site?

Tags: seo, google, domains, search-engine-indexing

We have moved our domain name to a brand new site and we would like to use the old site (now without a domain) with a new domain name and use the same template we used before with the previous domain. Will this create some issues (downranking both old and new site, etc..)?

Comment: Is the content for your new site with old domain different than your old site with the new domain? If so, you should be fine. Google will crawl the two sites and index them according to the content it finds at each site. If the content is the same between the two sites, you might run into [duplicate content](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/duplicate-content) issues. You'll want to work on getting the old site with new domain indexed, and the old domain with new site [re-crawled](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/ask-google-to-recrawl).

Comment: Other than the home page, does the new site use any of the same URL paths as the old site?